# How do I combine subquery rows into one column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with FileNet. I'm trying to get the folders that a document may be filed in to appear in one column of the record set delimited with semicolons. This was the layout previously decided on and I am tasked with making Oracle do it. Here's what I have for a query so far:

```
SELECT d1.F_DOCNUMBER,
d1.F_DOCCLASSNUMBER,
d1.F_ENTRYDATE,
d1.F_ARCHIVEDATE,
d1.F_RETENTBASE,
d1.F_RETENTDISP,
d1.F_RETENTOFFSET,
d1.F_PAGES,
d1.F_DOCTYPE,
d1.F_DOCFORMAT,
d1.A32 AS CERT_NUM,
d1.A35 AS DOC_TYPE,
d1.A36 AS BATCH_KEY,
d1.A37 AS FIELD_REP_CODE,
d1.A38 AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
d1.A39 AS VOUCH_NUM_HIGH,
d1.A40 AS VOUCH_NUM_LOW,
f1.Folders
FROM doctaba d1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (F_FOLDERNAME , ';'), 2) Folders
    FROM (SELECT fc2.F_DOCNUMBER, f2.F_FOLDERNAME, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY f2.F_FOLDERNAME) rn, COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
            FROM folder_contents fc2
            INNER JOIN folder f2
            ON f2.F_FOLDERNUMBER = fc2.F_FOLDERNUMBER
            WHERE fc2.F_DOCNUMBER = d1.F_DOCNUMBER)
    WHERE rn = cnt
    START WITH rn = 1
    CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1) f1
ON d1.F_DOCNUMBER = f1.F_DOCNUMBER
WHERE d1.F_DOCTYPE IS NULL
AND d1.F_DOCNUMBER >= 107777
AND d1.F_DOCNUMBER <= 305791
ORDER BY d1.F_DOCNUMBER;
```

The problem is that d1.F_DOCNUMBER is being marked as an invalid identifier. I read on some forums that Oracle may not let that column identifier work multiple query levels down. Anyone have some suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's my original query that just includes the folder values in rows.

```
SELECT doctaba.F_DOCNUMBER,
doctaba.F_DOCCLASSNUMBER,
doctaba.F_ENTRYDATE,
doctaba.F_ARCHIVEDATE,
doctaba.F_RETENTBASE,
doctaba.F_RETENTDISP,
doctaba.F_RETENTOFFSET,
doctaba.F_PAGES,
doctaba.F_DOCTYPE,
doctaba.F_DOCFORMAT,
doctaba.A32 AS CERT_NUM,
doctaba.A35 AS DOC_TYPE,
doctaba.A36 AS BATCH_KEY,
doctaba.A37 AS FIELD_REP_CODE,
doctaba.A38 AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
doctaba.A39 AS VOUCH_NUM_HIGH,
doctaba.A40 AS VOUCH_NUM_LOW,
folder.F_FOLDERNAME
FROM doctaba
LEFT JOIN folder_contents
ON doctaba.F_DOCNUMBER = folder_contents.F_DOCNUMBER
INNER JOIN folder
ON folder.F_FOLDERNUMBER = folder_contents.F_FOLDERNUMBER
WHERE doctaba.F_DOCTYPE IS NULL
AND doctaba.F_DOCNUMBER >= 107777
AND doctaba.F_DOCNUMBER <= 17208174
ORDER BY doctaba.F_DOCNUMBER;
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
CORE 9.2.0.8.0 Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are lucky.  You are only getting one value from the subquery, so you can just make it a correlated subquery in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (F_FOLDERNAME , ';'), 2) as Folders
        FROM (SELECT fc2.F_DOCNUMBER, f2.F_FOLDERNAME,
                     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY f2.F_FOLDERNAME) rn,
                     COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
              FROM folder_contents fc2 INNER JOIN
                   folder f2
                   ON f2.F_FOLDERNUMBER = fc2.F_FOLDERNUMBER
              WHERE fc2.F_DOCNUMBER = d1.F_DOCNUMBER
             )
        WHERE rn = cnt
        START WITH rn = 1
        CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1
       ) as Folders
FROM doctaba d1
WHERE d1.F_DOCTYPE IS NULL AND
      d1.F_DOCNUMBER >= 107777 AND
      d1.F_DOCNUMBER <= 305791
ORDER BY d1.F_DOCNUMBER;
```

Comment: I'm still getting an invalid identifier error with d1.F_DOCNUMBER. It doesn't say specifically in DBViz, but I assume it is referring to the F_DOCNUMBER in the subquery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DougDawson . . . Are you sure that both `folder_contents` and `doctaba` have fields called `F_DOCNUMBER`?

Comment: Yeah, I created my query based on the FileNet docs that I have. My original query (that had a row per folder) worked fine. Originally, this output was created by an application that used the FileNet API. It made it easier for them to concatenate the folder values. But, the FileNet client is too slow to pull 17 million records out.

Comment: I'll add my original query to my question.